# In Python is it possible to have a Stream based socket and a PIpe used asynchronously?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been searching high and low for 10 days now trying to find an example where there is an asynchronous streams socket (I need to use receiveuntil()) and a multiprocessing Pipe in use in the same script?

I like asyncio as I can await data arrival for the socket and the pipe. At least it seems like I should be able to.

The problem statement is:
Create 4 classes: myapp, task1, task2, and task3
In myapp create two multiprocessing Pipes, Pipe1 and Pipe2. Starts a process for Task1 passing in Pipe1. Starts Task2 passing in Pipe1 and Pipe2. Starts a process for Task3 passing in Pipe2.

Task1 uses Pipe1 to communicate with Task2. Task2 uses Pipe1 to talk to Task1 and Pipe2 to talk to Task3. And Task3 uses Pipe2 to talk to Task2.

Task1 also has a streams type socket so receiveuntil() can be used. Task3 needs to read/write a USB port.

Because of the other functions these tasks must do, some CPU intensive, all communications need to be asynchronous. I thought this should be easy, just register callbacks and us await to prevent blocking. So far, I cannot figure out how to do this. Starting processes seems pretty easy, but the communications is anything but.

So, can this be done? Anyone have an example of such a configuration for say Task1, I can extrapolate from there, I think.

Comment: 10 days, and you haven't taken the expedient out of using threads?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If you are asking why I haven't gone to threads, as much as I like the idea, I have the impression that, based on my reading, there were "better" ways to do this. Seems you are implying that Threads is the easy or maybe the best way, you could be right.

Comment: Easy, definitely. "Best", _shrug_. The places where asyncio wins out over threads tend to be at a place where you've got a lot of them (and are doing almost nothing that's CPU-intensive). The places where threads clearly win out over asyncio are places where you're doing calls into a library with a synchronous API (that doesn't hold the GIL for the full duration of its operation) and want to keep handling IO in the background while it runs. Between those points you've got places where one wins out a little, or the other, or it doesn't really matter.

Comment: And eventually asyncio in one thread will get bottlenecked on availability of that thread and you'll need more than the one anyhow.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, this is pretty much how I am beginning to feel about Python, in general!  Next step is a threaded one. I have a test app that has 3 classes. Two of the classes run as processes and the third just gets everyone going. A Pipe exists between them. The class with asyncio streams socket and one just reads the pipe, turns around the string as sends it back. I can tell you, for whatever reason, this does not work well! I have another single script test with a pipe between two processes. One way comms between them works like a hose! Very annoying!

Comment: Is it the classes? Is it one process has an asyncio socket?I have no earthly idea!!! Maybe using a pipe after reading and before writing a socket causes some kind of insanity. Haven't seen that written anywhere. Logically, it would seem ok.

Comment: If you have a concrete implementation, building a [mre] off it to include in the question would let us provide much more practical feedback.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That kinda was the problem, I was looking for a simple example and did not have one to really offer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, they can. In fact by using asyncio Tasks it can be done. Start a task that starts the socket server and has a coroutine to handle the connection etc. Start another task using another coroutine to handle the pipe/queue read. I am reasonably certain this can be done with threads as well but preferred to stay with asyncio.